# vsCode and cssComb

Tags: visual-studio-code, csslint, csscomb

Have used ***Brackets***, but had some problems.
Now trying to get into ***vsCode***.

I am a bit confused by the instructions available for setting up and using ***cssComb*** within vsCode.
Tried to use it from ***F1*** but it gave me the error : 
 **"command 'csscomb.execute' not found"**

Where do I set up the Configuration files ?

Would appreciate links to instructions that someone like myself can follow.

File Manager table of my "Workspace" :

```
 Drive M: ......................
    Workspace ..................
        Editing ................
        Testing ................
        Training ...............
```

.
cheers

Answer (score 0):

The csscomb docs are outdated. To install the extension, use the VS Code menu bar:

1. `View` > `Command Pallette`
2. Search "Install Extension"
3. Search the Extensions sidebar for "csscomb" and click Install

Related reading

1. https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/tips-and-tricks#_command-palette
2. https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/extension-gallery#_browse-for-extensions